# How can I prevent an application from changing the sound volume on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, sound-volume

How can I prevent an application from changing the sound volume on iPad?

Sound setting:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Doesn’t the OS handle this instead of apps?

Comment: @bmike some programs such as bluejeans manages to increase the volume

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot change anything on the iOS / iPadOS system.

Comment: @DarwinOSX thanks, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.